# Margin issue when resolution increases

Tags: html, css

I just noticed a resolution issue with a site I am creating, and as I am pretty new to HTML & CSS, I really can't figure out how to fix it.

here is the page where the issue occurs : http://website213.com/tour

I need to make the Right elements of the page lined all together, but as soon as the resolution increases a bit, it gets messy !!

Kindly help me fix this issue.

Best,

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: So, you are trying to line up the elements on the right? And a little code will make it a lot easier to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the **positioning**. Some elements are absolute, some are relative and some seem to be fixed. It would be impossible to go one by one, you will have to see how the whole site is being constructed.

I recommend you start by reading how positions work. They are really easy to understand, but if you haven't read about them they can ruin your life. Just do a search for css positioning or check this link: [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys, 

I m heading to lurn CSS Positionning in depth, hope it will helps me solve my issue, 

Best wishes to everyone

Comment: Once you get started, if you find any issues come back and ask. Ah, don't forget to tick the answer if it helped you :)